# any one help out React Native Video Compression?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ffmpeg, react-native-video, video-compression

Hello Friends I try to **Compress video in React native** app
I already use https://github.com/shahen94/react-native-video-processing but I didn't get actual reduce video file size.

I try to implement  https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ffmpeg package and try to compile but its gives **return code 1 and fails** process and in this process I use
**-y -i ${val} -c copy -map 0:v libx264 -b:v 0.5M -c:a aac -b:a 1000k ${data}** {val is input video file and data is output video file }

my code:    `RNFFprobe.getMediaInformation(val).then(information => { console.log('Result: ' + JSON.stringify(information)); });`-y -i ${val} -c copy -map 0:v libx264 -b:v 0.5M -c:a aac -b:a 1000k ${data} `const data=val RNFFmpeg.executeAsync(` -i ${val} -c copy -map 0:v libx264 -b:v 0.5M -c:a aac -b:a 1000k ${data}`, completedExecution => { if (completedExecution.returnCode === 0) { console.log("FFmpeg process completed successfully"); } else { console.log(`FFmpeg process failed with rc=${completedExecution.returnCode}.`); } }).then(executionId => console.log(`Async FFmpeg process started with executionId ${executionId}.`)) .catch(error=>console.log(error))`

[my compression code for ffmpeg image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiS6V.png)

Comment: Your ffmpeg command is invalid. You should test it manually before trying to script it. Should be `-y -i ${val} -map 0:v -c:v libx264 -b:v 0.5M -c:a aac -b:a 1000k ${data}`

Answer (score 0):

Did you prepare output file for ffmpeg execution?
Try using [`react-native-fs`](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) with ffmpeg like this.

```
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
import { FFmpegKit, FFprobeKit } from 'ffmpeg-kit-react-native';
...
const filename = _filename?.join('_') + cuid() + `.mp4`;
const outputPath = `${RNFS.CachesDirectoryPath}/${filename}`;
const executeSession = await FFmpegKit.execute(
  `-y -i ${video.path} -c:v mpeg4 -crf 24 ${outputPath}`,
);

if (returnCode.isValueCancel()) throw new Error('Canceled FFmpeg');
if (returnCode.isValueError()) throw new Error('FFmpeg Execution Error');

const session = await FFprobeKit.getMediaInformation(outputPath);
const information = session.getMediaInformation();
// get Information with information.getAllProperties() etc...
// fetch data from outputPath for upload etc...
```